# List of words with List Index

Tags: list, dictionary, split, slice

> Kindly help me on that. so far I did.

```
stopwords=['what','hello','and','at','is','am','i','to','the']
search_list=['where is north and northern side','finding the index'
             'ask in the community at western environmental',
             'my name is alan and i am coming from london southeast','access to the index']

rev_dict ={'east': 'e', 'eastern': 'e', 'enviornment': 'env', 'environ.': 
'env','environmental': 'env', 'north': 'n', 'northern': 'n', 'south': 's',
'southern': 's', 'west': 'w', 'western': 'w'}

result = [" ".join([rev_dict.get(x,x) for x in s.split() if x not in 
stopwords]) for s in search_list]

print (result)
```

> while run the above codes it gives the below output

```
['where n n side', 'finding index','ask in community w env', 'my name alan coming from london southeast','access index']
```

> **Help:**
>    If each search_list string has less than or equal to 20 characters(including space) then it should not apply the 'stopwords and rev_dict' steps and print the string as it is. If each string has above 20 characters only I should apply both 'stopwords and rev_dict' steps.
>
> What should I change the above code to get my below desirable output. **'finding the index'** and **'access to the index'** has to print as it is because they have less than or equal to 20 characters.

```
['where n n side', 'finding the index','ask in community w env', 'my name alan coming from london southeast','access to the index']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stopwords=['what','hello','and','at','is','am','i','to','the']
search_list=['where is north and northern side','finding the index',
             'ask in the community at western environmental',
             'my name is alan and i am coming from london southeast','access to the index']

rev_dict ={'east': 'e', 'eastern': 'e', 'enviornment': 'env', 'environ.': 
'env','environmental': 'env', 'north': 'n', 'northern': 'n', 'south': 's',
'southern': 's', 'west': 'w', 'western': 'w'}

result = [" ".join([rev_dict.get(x,x) for x in s.split() if x not in 
stopwords]) if len(s) > 20 else s for s in search_list]

print (result)
```

output:

```
['where n n side', 'finding the index', 'ask in community w env', 'my name alan coming from london southeast', 'access to the index']
```

use `if len(s) > 20` will solve it.